# How do i compare dates?

Tags: c++

I have date in string type then I need to compare these 2 dates

I've tried this but it shows me strange output

```
string str="2019-1-12";
    string str1="2019-1-13";
    tm timeDate;
    tm timeDate1;
    strptime(str.c_str(),"%Y-%m-%d ", &timeDate); 
    time_t time_input = mktime(&timeDate);
    strptime(str1.c_str(),"%Y-%m-%d ", &timeDate1); 
    time_t time_input1 = mktime(&timeDate1);

    double timeDiff = difftime(time_input,time_input1);
    cout<<timeDiff;
```

Comment: What do you mean, strange output? What output do you expect, and what do you see instead?

Comment: Did you check the return value from `strptime()`, which would indicate a parsing error, thus all the `tm` structures are still uninitialized garbage?

Comment: Are you trying to find out the number of seconds between two dates at local time 00:00:00?  Or are you trying to find out if one date is less than, equal to, or greater than another date?

Comment: @HowardHinnant less than,equal to,greather than another date

Answer (score 5):

Make it

```
tm timeDate = {};
tm timeDate1 = {};
```

In other words, initialize all members of `tm` structures to zero before `strptime` call. `strptime` only fills those members for which there's a format specifier; the rest remains garbage.

With this change, [your code works](https://rextester.com/QBPT10541)

Answer (score 0):

> less than,equal to,greather than another date

When your dates are strings in the format of "YYYY-mm-dd", this is a special case where the less-than operator for string gives the same result as the less-than operator would for a hypothetical date class.  This is because the date is stored in "big endian" format, each number in the date is also "big endian".

The string less-than operator compares each character one-by-one and if one is less than the other, then that is the result of the entire comparison.

The only thing you need to do is to make sure that your month and day fields are each two characters (put a zero in front if they are one character), and then compare the strings.

```
cout << (str < str1) << '\n';
```

Ditto for equality comparison.

Comment: is that only for "YYYY-mm-dd"?

Comment: It will work for any "big endian" variant.  In this context, "big endian" means:  year first, then month, then day, with each represented by a consistent number of digits.  For example it would also work with YYYYmmdd.

Comment: is thre any way to find difference between days using string?If not what better way to find difference

Comment: I recommend my free, open-source, header-only, date.h library: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html .  Parse the strings into `date::sys_days` and then subtract them to get `date::days`, which is a `chrono::duration`.